# objective C Regex

Tags: iphone, objective-c, regex, ios4

What is the objective C Regex equivalent for

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust\s*:\s*.*['|"|;|>]
```

where I would like to test

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust (any number of spaces) : (any number of spaces) (any length of characters) end with ('|"|;|>).
```

so this should pass

```
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa"
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa>
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa'
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     "saasasa";
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     'saasasa';
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     "100%";
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     '100%';
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     100;'
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     "100";
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     '100'>
    -webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa"
```

and this should fail

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa}
-webkit-text-size-adjust  :     saasasa^
```

etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSError* yourError = nil;
NSRegularExpression* yourRegex = [NSRegularExpression
   regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\s*:\s*['\"]?[a-z0-9]+%?['\";>]+" 
                        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                          error:&yourError];

[yourRegex numberOfMatchesInString:yourString 
                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                             range:NSMakeRange(0, [yourString  length])];
```

Comment: hence the %? (? means one or zero)